# How do I force an activity to use the intent extras I pass it?

Tags: android

I have a stack of activities, and use the following code to bring the main activity to the 'active' state:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.putExtra("clearCache", true);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

The problem is that when I try to retrieve the `clearCache` extra, a call to `getIntent().getExtras()` returns null.

My understanding is that because the activity that I'm launching was already on the stack, and because I set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag, the Intent that gets returned will be the original intent.

How do I access the calling intent in the activity I'm launching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the google documentation on FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, you should be getting the new intent each time:

"If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent."

...

"The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will either receive the new intent you are starting here in its onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent()."

For more details take a look here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Overriding `onNewIntent()` and then handling the new intent from there solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You just change your code by passing the particular Activity name and keep the rest of code as it is,

```
Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("clearCache", true);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
```